# VPS OS Debian 6 : how the VPS configuration that can be accessed with a browser IP:PORT

Tags: apache, debian, vps

I'm new for VPS (OS Debian 6). The following is that I have tried:

1. create file : var/www/say-hello/index.php
2. copy and edit file : /etc/apache2/sites-available# cp default say-hello
3. /etc/apache2/sites-available# a2dissite default
4. /etc/apache2/sites-available# a2ensite say-hello
5. /etc/init.d/apache2 reload

apache reload **success** with no displaying error, but displaying '**[warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts**'

and here is the **say-hello file** I have to change from the **default file**:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:10000>
   ServerPath /var/www/say-hello
   # just so apache invokes suexec (fastcgiwrapper) on fastcgi request
   SuexecUserGroup www-data www-data
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to access via browser : http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:10000/index.php (xx is IP for VPS), but not work
with browser error *'The connection has timed out'*

my question:
whether there are other configurations or there is something wrong with the steps I did?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you have defined to be the page in the port 10000, you need to open that port, in /etc/apache2/ports.conf, adding a line that tells apache to listen in 10000.
Like this:

```
# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

Listen 80
Listen 10000

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Then restart apache.

/etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Assuming you don't have the port firewwaled.
Hope this helps.

Comment: nice, it's work with adding a rule in iptables in debian to open a new port,, thank's for your help... :-)